# Is there an easy to use tab control for visual studio 6?

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, user-controls

I need to support a legacy vb6 application, and would like to add a tab control.  Is there an equivalent to visual studio 2008's tab control?  The built-in "TabStrip" control is a pain to use.

Comment: "The built-in "TabStrip" control is a pain to use." - what specifically?

Comment: The most common complaint about `TabStrip` is that it is not actually a container. You have to write your own code to switch the controls when the tab changes. (It's not actually that hard once you get used to it. The typical solution is a control array of Frames.) Here's the page from the VB6 docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443489(VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 3):

It comes included with Visual Basic 6.  Go to the Projects/Component menu, then select Microsoft Tabbed Dialog Control 6.0.

This is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: +1. This is indeed exactly what you are looking for. Here's the description from the VB6 manual. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733699(VS.60).aspx  I also recommend reading some of the knowledgebase articles as there are some pitfalls with this control http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&&q=sstab+knowledgebase+site%3Amicrosoft.com&meta=&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Answer (score 2):

**Visual Studio Style Tab Control for VB6**
http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/vb/code/controls/Tab_Controls/Visual_Studio_Style_Tab_Control/article.asp

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can still get it, I loved [ComponentOne's SizerOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/SizerOne/) controls. It comes with a very easy to use tab control.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Tab Control in Microsoft Windows Common Control 6 (`MSCOMCTL.OCX`) or 5 (`COMCTL32.OCX`)

Comment: That is exactly what he does not want.

Comment: -1, sorry. But as AngryHacker says, this is the same `TabStrip` control that the question complains about, and alternatives are sought.